# How to access data from UnityCatalog metastore outside of Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Is there any way to query data from the unity catalog metastore using local spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual data isn't stored in the Unity Catalog - it's stored in the actual cloud storage, so if you have correct credentials, then you can access data using the Spark outside of the Databricks. Unity Catalog acts as a catalog for metadata about your data locations, schema, etc.  And [there will be an ability to use Unity Catalog via Hive Metastore interface](https://www.databricks.com/blog/extending-databricks-unity-catalog-open-apache-hive-metastore-api) - specifically done for external access to the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do I understand correctly that for now there is no way to read tables directly like from hive metastore?

Comment: With upcoming Hive Metastore interface it will be possible, but table is just a bunch files on the disk, so if you know the location & have credentials, then you can just do `spark.read.format("delta").load("s3a://.....")`